# Declaring a variable of self-referencing generic type in C# 10.0

Tags: c#, generics, builder, self-reference, fluent-interface

Good time of the day!

I have a generic interface which has a self-reference:

```csharp
public interface IBuilder<TObject, TBuilder>
    where TBuilder : IBuilder<TObject, TBuilder>
{
    public TObject Build();
}
```

so I can use it like this:

```csharp
public abstract class Builder<TObject, TBuilder> : IBuilder<TObject, TBuilder>
    where TBuilder : Builder<TObject, TBuilder>
{
    protected TObject obj;
    protected readonly TBuilder @this;
    protected abstract TObject CreateObject();
    protected abstract void CheckBuildConstraints();

    public Builder()
    {
        obj = CreateObject();
        @this = (TBuilder)this;
    }

    public virtual TObject Build()
    {
        CheckBuildConstraints();
        return obj;
    }
}
```

```csharp
public interface IContext
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

```csharp
public interface IContextBuilder<TContext, TBuilder> : IBuilder<TContext, TBuilder>
    where TContext : IContext
    where TBuilder : IContextBuilder<TContext, TBuilder>
{
    //...

    TBuilder SetName(string name);
}
```

```csharp
public class Context : IContext
{
    public string Name => _name!;

    protected string? _name;

    protected Context() { }

    public abstract class ContextBuilder<TContext, TBuilder>
        : Builder<TContext, TBuilder>, IContextBuilder<TContext, TBuilder>
        where TContext: Context
        where TBuilder : ContextBuilder<TContext, TBuilder>
    {
        public ContextBuilder() : base() { }

        protected override void CheckBuildConstraints()
        {
            obj._name ??= "default value";
        }

        //...

        public TBuilder SetName(string name)
        {
            obj._name = name;
            return @this;
        }
    }

    public class ContextBuilder : ContextBuilder<Context, ContextBuilder>
    {
        public ContextBuilder() : base() { }

        protected override Context CreateObject() => new();
    }
}
```

and then do these FluentAPI-style chained calls:

```csharp
var context = new Context.ContextBuilder().SetName("name").Build();
```

My questions are these:

1. Do I overcomplicate things? Is there any simpler way to do what I did?
2. How do I declare a variable of IContextBuilder<IContext, IContextBuilder<...>> type?

I have googled a lot of information and I have not been able to find anything usefull so far. I am hoping for your help. Cheers!

Comment: But to answer your first question: Yes! If you really wanna use builders then what's the problem with having a simple `class ContextBuilder { ... }` and using it like `new ContextBuilder().WithName("name").Build()`?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride That is just an example, I use this code to build quite complex objects which inherit each other and each other's builders.

Comment: If you need such a complex builder hierarchy to just create things, then maybe your class hierarchy is the problem?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride I want to use interface declaration so I could use dependency injection.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride I have a lot of similar objects with some common properties and and some different, so I use inheritance to not rewrite the same code a lot of times

Comment: You don't need interfaces for dependency injection. You could register builder classes directly just fine. You only need interfaces in DI if a) you want to dynamically change the implementations behind them during startup, or b) the dependencies have side effects you need to mock during unit testing.

Comment: Besides that: [inheritance is not for code reuse](https://www.google.com/search?q=inheritance+is+not+for+code+reuse&oq=inheritance+is+not+for+&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqBwgBEAAYgAQyBggAEEUYOTIHCAEQABiABDIICAIQABgWGB4yCAgDEAAYFhgeMggIBBAAGBYYHjIICAUQABgWGB4yCAgGEAAYFhgeMggIBxAAGBYYHjIICAgQABgWGB4yCggJEAAYhgMYigXSAQg1OTU5ajBqMagCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Thanks a lot, the provided information looks promising, I will try to change my classes/interfaces hierarchy to make it more clear. Also I would be happy if you could provide a couple of information sources on the subject.